Read Data from external Sensors
I would like to create an android app which monitors the room temperature.
Is it possible to connect a temperature sensor with cable (I do not want to be dependent on Wi-Fi and if possible not on Bluetooth as well) to the Smartphone and read out the temperature in my app?
I know SensorManager can access the temperature of the sensor, which is integrated in the smartphone, but i have read that this sensor does not give acuurate information about the room temperature. That's why i want to use an external temperature sensor.
I only found sensors, which communicate to existing apps, but it is not possible to access their temperature measurement inside my own app, is it?

"Is it possible to connect a temperature sensor with cable... to the Smartphone and read out the temperature in my app?" -- contact the sensor manufacturer and ask them.
